# How to Convert IEnumerable<T> to Task<IEnumerable<T>>for test mock's result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm testing a repository methods with 'Mock'. To accomplish this goal, I created a IList lists with the T model I'm testing(in this case a subject). However some of the methods return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` and I setup the mock list with IEnumerable which causes the following error message:

> System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with return type 'Task<IEnumerable>' cannot invoke callback with return type 'IEnumerable'.

this is the method GetAllAsync allocated in repository:

```
 Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

And This is the mock setup file:

```
    public class MockSubjectRepository
    {
        public static Mock<IRepositoryWrapper> GetMock()
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IRepositoryWrapper>();

            IEnumerable<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>()
            {
                new Subject()
                {
                    SubjectId = Guid.Parse("0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e"),
                    Title = "Math",
                    Credits = int.Parse("8"),
                    Students = new List<Student>()
                    {
                        new Student()
                        {
                            StudentId = new Guid(),
                            FirstName = "Alan",
                            SurName = "Shearer",
                            Email = "alan_shearer@gmail.com",
                            Password = "12345678",
                            EnrollmentDate = new DateTime()
                        }

                    },
                    Teacher = new Teacher()
                    {
                        TeacherId = new Guid(),
                        
                    }
                }
            };

         
            mock.Setup(m => m.Subject.GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(() =>  Task.FromResult(subjects)); #Cause the error message
}
}
```

Now could you help me to transform the `IEnumerable<Subject> subject` to `Task<IEnumerable<Subject>> subject`, so I can test it well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Task.FromResult method to wrap your IEnumerable in a completed Task:

```
public class MockSubjectRepository
{
    public static Mock<IRepositoryWrapper> GetMock()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IRepositoryWrapper>();

        IEnumerable<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>()
        {
            // .....
        };

        Task<IEnumerable<Subject>> subjectTask = Task.FromResult(subjects);

        mock.Setup(m => m.Subject.GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(() => subjectTask);

        return mock;
    }
}
```